# Azure Storage Python sdk - get_container_access_policy Not Working

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a problem when trying to run  ([get_container_access_policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-get-container-access-policy/) from the Azure Storage Python sdk.

I tried doing the following:

```
account_url = <account_url>
credential = ClientSecretCredential(client_secret=client_secret, client_id=client_id, tenant_id=tenant_id)
blob_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credential)
container_client = blob_client.get_container_client("container_name")
access_policy = container_client.get_container_access_policy()
```

This does not work, I get the error *The specified resource does not exist* (although the container does exist).
Other requests, such as *get_container_properties*, do work!

However, when I create the blob client using

```
BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
```

The get_container_access_policy request works.
I don't want to work with a connection string (and frankly I don't know why this method works and the other one doesn't).
Is there any workaround for this? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to work with a connection string (and frankly I don't
> know why this method works and the other one doesn't). Is there any
> workaround for this? What should I do?

The reason you are getting this error is because [`Get Container ACL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-container-acl) operation does not support Azure AD based authorization. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory#permissions-for-blob-service-operations):

[image]

Right now your only option would be to make use of Shared Key authorization using account name and key.